# I am creating a Django budgeting website and my changing status is not working

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

view-bills-admin.html

```html
{% extends "base/room_home.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="min-height: 100vh;">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>{{ room_bills.title }}</h1>
        <p>Due: {{ room_bills.due }}</p>

        <div class="col-3">
            <h3>Paid Members: </h3>
            <ul>
                {% for submission in submissions %}
                <li>
                    <a href="proof/{{ submission.user.id }}" target="_blank">{{ submission.user.username }} {{ submission.text }}</a>
                    <form>
                        <label for="status">Status:</label>
                        <select name="status" id="{{ submission.id }}" onblur="postStatus('{{ submission.id }}')">
                            <option value="P">Pending</option>
                            <option value="A">Accepted</option>
                            <option value="R">Rejected</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <h3>Did not pay members: </h3>
            <ul>
                {% for user in did_not_submit %}
                    <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Move the function outside the DOMContentLoaded event listener
    function postStatus(submissionId) {
        const selectElement = document.getElementById(submissionId);
        const status = selectElement.value;

        fetch(`/room/{{ room.join_code }}/bills/{{ bills.slug }}/status/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "submissionId": submissionId,
                "status": status
            })
        });
    }
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def remark_proof_api(request, room_id, bills_slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        submission_id = data["submission_id"]
        status = data["status"]
        sub = Submission.objects.get(id=int(submission_id))
        sub.status = status
        sub.save()
        
        return JsonResponse({"success": True})
```

urls.py

```py
path('room/<str:room_id>/bills/<str:bills_slug>/status/', views.remark_proof_api, name='remark-proof'),
```

I want the status to be changed but it doesn't work, every time I refresh it keeps on going back to pending which is the default.

Comment: Post your `Submission` model please.

Comment: class Submission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bills = models.ForeignKey(bills, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    proof = models.FileField(null=True)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('P', 'Pending'), ('A', 'Accepted'), ('R', 'Rejected'))

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='P')

Comment: Edit your question and add the model there, properly formatted. This is not readable. Also include overridden methods, if any (such as `.save()`).

Answer (score -1):

make sure to include the CSRF token in the headers like this.

```
headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            },
```

Here is an example in the documentation using AJAX and a getCookie function for retrieving csrftoken. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/.

Comment: The view is `@csrf_exempt`.